# Webform2PDF doesn't display arabic characters

Tags: webforms, files

I'm using [webform2pdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform2pdf) with [TCPDF library](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) to generate pdf of submissions, I have some arabic words in the submissions, the generetaed pdf doesn't display them.
Is there any config to do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It solved, I just changed the font to 'DejaVu Sans' in Generate-PDF settings.